# .NET Core display Assembly Version

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor

In ASP.Net MVC, It's easy to display on a page a websites version/build #. The '*' allows a new hash value for each build, thus it is easy to tell what version a running website corresponds to for a specific build checked into source control.
Is there an equivalent type of functionality in .NET Core?

ASP.Net MVC:
**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - @Html.AssemblyVersion()</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET core MVC app, you can do like this.

```
public class VersionHelper
{
    public static string GetAssemblyVersion()
    {
        AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute infoVersion = (AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        return infoVersion.InformationalVersion;
    }
}
```

and in Index.cshtml or _layout.cshtml, wherever your footer is defined.

```
<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - @VersionHelper.GetAssemblyVersion()</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Since it's displayed on every page, I would cache the value in a field. `public static string Version { get; } = typeof(<something>).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion;`

Comment: This gives the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute, not the AssemblyVersionAttribute. They are diffent things, AssemblyVersionAttribute doesn't seem to be listed in the RuntimeAssembly that GetExecutingAssembly() returns.